# Setting UICollectionViewLayout causes a crash

Tags: uicollectionview

sometimes setting collectionViewLayout when app launch, causes this fatal exception:

Do you have an idea why?

There is no update since it's during app launch. 
And I am not able to reproduce it. 
I got a lot of crashes from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Cannot set the layout [<StreamContainerLayoutIPad: 0x1056a4e60>] for [<DMZFixedCollectionView: 0x10593f600; baseClass = UICollectionView; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x283906640>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2837dd1a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewLayout: 0x10566f620>] during an update.
```

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x183df7ea0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182fc9a40 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183d0dc1c +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x1847fb140 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1b089ac4c -[UICollectionView _setCollectionViewLayout:animated:isInteractive:completion:animator:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1b089aaa8 -[UICollectionView _setCollectionViewLayout:animated:isInteractive:completion:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1b089a668 -[UICollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:]
7  Vero                           0x1048f52e4 -[StreamCompressionController setup] (__hidden#27104_:77)
8  Vero                           0x10491d0ac -[StreamMainViewController viewWillAppear:] (__hidden#26011_:227)
9  UIKitCore                      0x1b0a038ec -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1b0a03fd0 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:]
```

Here is my code in setup method:

```
- (void)setup
{
    CollectionLayout *newLayout = [self createLayout];
    _collectionView.collectionViewLayout = newLayout;
    _layout = newLayout;
}
```

PS: What is strange is that is occurred only on iPhone and not on iPad.

Comment: Show the code of `setup` method of `StreamCompressionController`. Did you set the layout at least?

Comment: yes of course! :) I added it.

Comment: Could you check if `newLayout` is `nil`? What's the code of `createLayout`?

Comment: this cannot be this cause. I would get:
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout cannot be nil in setCollectionViewLayout:'

Comment: Ok, note that your layout is of class with name "iPad" (is it normal?), is it normal? Also, the end message is "during an update", so maybe you should do it earlier or later, you seem to (re)load(data) the UICollectionView at that time causing the issue.

Comment: Yes iPad in name is normal.

Comment: should I call invalidateLayout before setting new layout?